# Why do my modules not work after transferring my magento site to another server?

Tags: magento-1.8, module, extensions, localisation, magento-connect

I'm trying to move my magento site to another server.

I do this transfer multiple archives: theme files (app.tar skin.tar), images (media.tar), module` s files (local.tar, community.tar) and local.xml, bitnami_magento.sql

I almost succeeded. But I have a problem. Modules are not installed. Please see the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwgCH.png

So my site has no localization (through translation module), a blog (via AW Blog), One Page Checkout, and still does not work the other modules.

Maybe someone faced with this problem?

Need any advice or decision.
Thanks

Comment: Feel free to thank @huzefam by accepting his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

check if you have moved your module definition files in `app/etc/modules`